# Take user from one page to the other with a value

Tags: php

How do you redirect in PHP with a value? I'm a newbie please. I need to redirect but with a value. i know this in c# and Cobol. Not sure about php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a header.

```
header('location:your_page.php?your_value='.$your_value.'');
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks alot @william.